# Hide/show div with click of button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to hide/show a div based on the click of a button but I can't get it to work.

Below is my code. I can get the alert to see that I'm getting the right ID from the DOM, but I can't show/hide the div content.

```js
function toggleContent(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  //if(e.style.display == null || e.style.display == "none") 
  if (e.style.visibility == null || e.style.visibility == "hidden") {
    //e.style.display = "block";
    e.style.visibility: "visible";
  } else {
    //e.style.display = "none";
    e.style.visibility: "hidden";
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button onclick="alertData();">Get Alerts</button>
  <button onclick="toggleContent('chart');">Chart</button>
  <hr>
  <div id="chart" style="visibility: hidden;">
    my chart
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Use jquery function: toggle(). its easier: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: It looks like you just have a syntax error.  To set the visibility, use an equals sign, not a colon.

Comment: i tried the above and it did a flash but didn't stay on the page

Comment: @will2m Either remove the form or add `type="button"` to your buttons.

Comment: well spotted  Josiah, didn't even notice it was in a form. You could also add event.preventDefault(); in the script. might add it to my answer in case it's put in the form

Answer (score 6):

You need to set `e.style.visibility` using `=`, not `:` as you would in a CSS file.

In addition, note that the value `null` is equivalent to `visible`, not `hidden`.

```js
function toggleContent(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  
  if (e.style.visibility == "hidden") {
    e.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    e.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <button onclick="alertData();">Get Alerts</button>
  <button onclick="toggleContent('chart');">Chart</button>
  <hr>
  <div id="chart" style="visibility: hidden;">
    my chart
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toggleContent(id) {
 event.preventDefault();
var e = document.getElementById(id);
   
   e.style.visibility=="hidden" || e.style.visibility=="" ? e.style.visibility="visible": e.style.visibility="hidden";
   }
```

```css
#chart{visibility:hidden;}
```

```html
<form>
  <button onclick="toggleContent('chart');">Chart</button> 
    <hr>
        <div id="chart">
            my chart
        </div></form>
```

Comment: same - gave me a flash only. plus i need to hide on page load

Comment: edited answer, it does hide on page load if you add the css to your css file, if not add the inline style again, added preventDefault to stop the form submission which is causing the page flash, ie page reload